# How do I configure audit of sensitive data groups in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, auditing

Attempting to configure the "sensitive" versions of the batch completed groups (SENSITIVE_BATCH_STARTED_GROUP/SENSITIVE_BATCH_COMPLETED_GROUP) that are listed in the doc for SQL 2019

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/auditing/sql-server-audit-action-groups-and-actions?view=sql-server-ver15

I have set up all the data classifications and now need to set up the associated auditing.

Issue is I can't select them in the UI (they're not in the dropdown list) nor can I use them in T-SQL or PowerShell scripts either.

E.g. Whilst using BATCH_STARTED_GROUP works just fine, replacing just those characters in the same script with SENSITIVE_BATCH_STARTED_GROUP produces a syntax error but according to the doc it should be fine.

[image]

Am I missing a configuration option or something similar ?

Running SQL 2019 (15.0.4223.1)

Comment: I suspect the docs are simply wrong here, and this particular event is supported only on Azure SQL (and presumably will be supported in SQL Server 2022 as well). If you do `select * from sys.dm_audit_actions where name like '%batch%'`, you'll see these actions are not included in the system catalogs.